# Как прямоугольную выделяемую область во всём приложении заменить на круглую?

Tags: java, android

Если показывать наглядно, то вместо этого [image: этого]я хочу получить вот это[image: это]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, мне надо было всего-лишь удалить строчку `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` из манифеста

Answer (score 2):

Описанное поведение чаще всего встречается в `Material BottomNavigationView`. Вот например есть такая разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

дальше вот пример менюшки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

и вот поведение которое вам нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [документация](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#placement) по данному вью.

Comment: У меня абсолютно такой же код. Я использую именно Material BottomNavigationView. Как тему приложения использую Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight. Тему пробовал менять, от неё ничего не зависит. Пробовал создать через галерею активити шаблон с готовым Bottom Navigation и в своём проекте, и в абсолютно чистом. В абсолютно чистом проекте при зажатии при долгом удержании заполняется область круга, а в моём там наблюдается та же самая проблема. Абсолютно без понятия, что на это может влиять

Comment: В добавок, я говорю не конкретно про BottomNavigationView, а про все кликабельные области.

Comment: Что значит все кликабельные области?? Эта часть вообще не понятна